# Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'popover' in IE 9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'popover'.
Error is occurring in IE9.
Does any body had the same problem.

Comment: I am dealing with the same!

Comment: Probably the JS was not loaded. Next time, provide more info in your questions so we can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a script link to bootstrap and that should resolve your issue:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Or download bootstrap.min.js and add it locally.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am using drupal. Can you please let me know where I should add this code? <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>